# Vnc and Port Forwarding - Port and Display Number

Tags: vnc, port-forwarding

I have VNC running on my PI with the default port ("netstat -npl" suggests that is 5901).  I am trying to set up Port Forwarding on my router to let me VNC in to my PI from an external network.  I have my router configured to foward port 5000 to 5901 on the PI.

When I connect to my PI on the same LAN, I use Tight VNC Viewer with the PI's IP and specify :1 for the display.  For instance:

192.168.1.200:1

On my remote machine, in Tight VNC Viewer, I am trying to connect, but I need to specify the port.  TightVNC instructs you to do so using :: for the port, such as:

myDnsName::5000

That fails, presumably because I haven't included the :1 for the display number.  Is there a way to specify both the port and display number? "myDnsName:1:5000" and "myDnsName::5000:1" return errors.

Additionally, I tested the port forward of just 5901 to 5901.  From my remote machine trying just "myDnsName:1" did not work.

Edit:

It seems like my port forwarding settings didn't apply correctly.  Not sure how that heppened, D'oh!

Comment: By "mydnsname" do you mean public IP?

Comment: No, I meant the dynamic DNS Name pointing to my IP address.  Public IP would also work though.

Comment: please mark an answer as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of it

Answer (score 2):

From my experience when connecting to the PI you need to simply add the display number to the port number. For example when connecting to a VNC on display 1 you would use 
`your.ip.goes.here:5901` (instead of `your.ip.goes.here:1`)

If the VNC server was on display 2 you would use `your.ip.goes.here:5902`

Also make sure that the port you are forwarding is the same as the port on the pi, so if you want to connect to display one you would forward port 5901

Comment: This did it!  myDnsName::5901 worked.

Comment: At first I thought this was the solution, but It seems like my port forwarding settings didn't apply correctly.  myDnsName:5000 worked but NOT myDnsName:5001. Not sure how that heppened, D'oh!

Comment: Thanks, all the tutorials are telling you should connect to `vnc://<ip>:1` which is wrong. This did the trick for me on a MAC.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command below

```
myDnsName:1::5900
```

You wrote a similar command in your question as something that gave you an error. But you were missing a colon  before the port number. Please feel free to read more about vnc [here](http://tightvnc.com/vncviewer.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to access VNC from the WAN even though I setup port forwarding correctly.  I had to stop OpenVPN on Raspberry Pi with the command

```
sudo service openvpn@outgoing stop
```

then it worked